# Delete files of certain size range

Tags: bash, find, size

I want to delete files which size is between certain values. For example I have the following list of files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  558 Apr 30 13:07 stats.sfe.1.20120430130513.xml.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  388 Apr 30 15:32 stats.sfe.1.20120430153013.xml.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  386 Apr 30 15:36 stats.sfe.1.20120430153513.xml.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  389 Apr 30 15:42 stats.sfe.1.20120430154013.xml.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  390 Apr 30 16:02 stats.sfe.1.20120430160013.xml.Z
-rw-r--r-- 1 smsc sys  385 Apr 30 16:12 stats.sfe.1.20120430161013.xml.Z
```

From the above list, I want to delete only the files which size varies between **386b** and **390b**. I know that I can use the following command to delete files which size exceed certain `<size>`:

```
find . -size +<size>-delete
```

But how can I add one more boundary for files which size is less than a given value?

Comment: `find` conditions are logically AND'd by default, so just tack on another `-size` option for the other bound.

Comment: @jw013 Great! That works for me. Thanks! Please post it as your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A range is simply an upper bound *AND* a lower bound.  From the [`find` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> expression  [-a]  expression
>
> Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the juxtaposition of two primaries or made explicit by the optional -a operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false.

So all you need to do is specify both size bounds before the `-delete` action.

Answer (score 8):

The `-a` in an explicit `AND` operator that allows you to conjoin two primaries. In this case creating a range using `-size`.

`find . -size +386b -a -size -390b -exec rm -f {} \;`

Note the size is a numeric argument that can optionally be prepended with `+` and `-`. From `man 1 find`:

```
   Numeric arguments can be specified as

   +n     for greater than n,
   -n     for less than n,
    n      for exactly n.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as @jw013 mentioned in his comment, `find` conditions are logically AND'd by default. So I just added one more `size` condition and it worked fine! The final command looks like: `find . -maxdepth 1 -size +358c -size -395c -delete`

Answer (score 8):

Whenever `find` expects a number, you can put a `+` sign before it to mean more than this number, or a `-` sign to mean less than this number. These are strict inequalities: `+3` and `-7` means 4, 5 or 6.

With the `-size` primary, you need to add the suffix `c` to indicate that the number is a number of bytes. You can concatenate multiple primaries to take their conjunction (in some versions, you can put `-a` or `-and` between them). Thus:

```
find . -size +385c -size -391c -delete
```

In zsh, you can use the `L` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). The default unit is bytes; like `find`, the characters `+` and `-` indicate strict inequalities.

```
rm *(L+385-391)
```

(The command above does not recurse into subdirectories; if you need that, add `**/` before the pattern.)

Comment: I don't understand the +3 and -7 equalling 4, 5 or 6. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -e '
    for ( @ARGV ) { 
        if ( -s >= 386 && -s _ <= 390 ) { 
            unlink $_ or printf qq[%s\n], qq[Could not delete $_: $!] 
        } 
    }
' *
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Should this part of code be entered as a single line?

Comment: @EugeneS: Yes. It should work pasting it in your command line as-is or joining all lines into one.