# I need a script to delete files that are more than a certain size, in centos 7

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, deleted-files

Given the name and size of a file, if the files size is more then the given size it should be deleted.

Comment: Hi Michele, and welcome. What OS? What have you tried?

Comment: on centos 7 , Actually, I'm a Linux beginner and trying to try something

Comment: type `man find` and read. Combine `find` with the `rm` command. As it looks like your goal is to learn, I will not say any more. But feel free to come back if you get stuck. Be careful not to delete anything important. Top tip use `echo rm` for testing.

Comment: Very related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37627/delete-files-of-certain-size-range?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete files of certain size range](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37627/delete-files-of-certain-size-range)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The first command line parameter is the size limit
LIMIT="$1"

shift 1

# Now loop over the rest of the command line parameters, which are the file names to check.
for file in "$@"; do 
  SIZE="$(stat --format="%s" "$file")"
  if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$LIMIT" ]; then
    echo "$file is $SIZE bytes. Deleting..."
    rm "$file"
  fi
done
```

The size limit would be given as the first parameter and all filenames given after that.

For example, with a size limit of 400 bytes:

```
script.sh 400 file1 file2 file3 ... fileN
```

You could also use wildcards:

```
script.sh 600 *.txt file1 bigfile2*.log dir1/*.txt dir2/*.old
```

Comment: Always but always double-quote `"$@"` otherwise you lose its magic

Comment: @roaima Or even better, just use `for file do` to avoid the issue of quoting `$@`. But `shift 1` can be just `shift` and all variable expansions should be double quoted. Also, the `#!` line could be `#!/bin/sh` as there is nothing `bash`-y about this script.

Comment: Always double quote your variables when you use them unless you _really know_ why you don't need to. For example `"$file"`

Comment: All good comments. I was on the fence about complicating the example with the quotes, or leaving this simple for a beginner to understand. I think I'll fix the quotes to enforce good habits, but leave the $@ so it's more explicit what's going on...